# Best data structure for this operations

Tags: optimization, data-structures, ocaml

I'm trying to find a better approach that my current one to manage the current state vector of a continuous Markov chain. The state vector used stores pairs of (state, proability) where probability is a float.

The piece of the algorithm that needs to be optimized does the following operations:

- every iteration starts with a current state vector
- computes the reachable states for every current one in vector and store all of them in a temporary list together with the probability of going there
- for every element in this new list it calculates the new state vector by iterating over the possible transitions (mind that there can be many transitions which lead to the same state but found from different source states)

this is actually done by using *hashtables* that have as keys the states and as values the probabilities.

So basically to build up the new vector, for every transition, the normalized value is calculated, then the state in the vector is retrieved with a get, the probability of current transition is added and then the result is stored back.

This approach seemed to work so far but I'm trying to cope with systems that lead in very large space vectors (500k-1mil states) so, although hashtable give a constant complexity to store and retrieve, iterations starts slowing down really a lot.

This because for example, we start from a vector that has 100k states, for each one we computes the reachable states (which usually are > 1) so that we obtain a transition list of 100k*(avg reachable states). Then every transition is gone through to compute the new probability vector.

Unfortunately I need to go through the whole reachable list to find the normalizing value without actually computing the next vecto but in any case, as I saw through profiling, this is not the bottleneck of the algorithm. The bottleneck is present when every transition is computed.

This is the function used to compute the transition list from the current vector (`pi`):

```
HTable.fold (fun s p l ->
  if check s f2 then (0., s, p, [s, 1.0]) :: l
  else if not (check s f1) then (0., s, p, [s, 1.0]) :: l
  else
    let ts = P.rnext s in                         
    if List.length ts = 0 then (0., s, p, [s, 1.0]) :: l
    else
      let lm = List.fold_left (fun a (s,f) -> f +. a) 0. ts in
      (lm, s, p, ts) :: l) pi []
```

And this is the function that computes the new `pi` by going through the transition list and by normalizing them all:

```
let update_pi s v = 
  try
    let t = HTable.find pi s in
    HTable.replace pi s (v +. t)
  with Not_found -> HTable.add pi s v
in
  HTable.clear pi;
  List.iter (fun (llm, s, p, ts) ->
    if llm = 0. then
      update_pi s p
    else begin
      List.iter (fun (ss, pp) -> 
        update_pi ss (p *. (pp /. lm))
      ) ts;
      if llm < lm then update_pi s (p *. (1. -. (llm /. lm)))
    end 
  ) u;
```

I should find a data structures which is better suited for the operations I'm doing, the problem is that with current approach I have to do a get and a set for every single transition but doing so many operations over hashtables kills performance since the constant cost is quite expensive.

Comment: Not a full answer, but your update_pi function doesn't need to do a try -> find -> replace, with -> add.  A single replace will work.  From the OCaml docs: Hashtbl.replace tbl x y replaces the current binding of x in tbl by a binding of x to y. If x is unbound in tbl, a binding of x to y is added to tbl. This is functionally equivalent to Hashtbl.remove tbl x followed by Hashtbl.add tbl x y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot hurt to replace the linear time `if List.length ts = 0` by the constant time `if ts = []`, although I doubt this is going to solve your performance problem.

Your algorithm sound a little like multiplying a matrix by a vector to get a new vector. This is usually sped up by [blocking](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/autoblock/node2.html). But here, the representation in hashtables may be costing you locality. Would it be possible, once and for all, to number all the states, and then use arrays instead of hashtables? Note that with arbitrary transitions, the destination states would still not be local, but it may be an improvement (if only because accessing an array is more direct than accessing a hashtable).

Comment: The main purpose of this approach is to avoid using matrices and vectors because they won't fit in RAM.. this is why I have to use something different. I could numerate all the states but I need also the real state to compute the next wit `P.rnext`.. still walking in darkness :(

Comment: If they are bigger then RAM, you should look at a solution that utilizes the Ancient module (http://merjis.com/developers/ancient).